# border-bottom not working with absolute positioning

Tags: html, css

I am trying to position many elements on a website using absolute positioning. When I try to underline them (using border-bottom) as a group, it does not work.

An example code is:

```
<span style="border-bottom: 2px solid red;">
    <span style="position:absolute; left:50px; top:50px;">Hello</span> how are you
</span>
```

And I created a jsfiddle in case it helps: http://jsfiddle.net/smkexpza/

Comment: i do not see the problem you only have one span that have border if you want both of them to have border you should target the span element with your style and not use inline style may be i didn't understand what you need here

Comment: When you absolutely position an element, it's taken out of the flow of the document. That means that the absolutely-positioned `<span>` that contains "Hello" will not affect the dimensions of its parent, so a border-bottom will not be pushed down by its inclusion.

Comment: "I am trying to position many elements on a website using absolute positioning"...don't do that unless **completely necessary**. Absolute positioning is a very poor choice for **general layout**. There are much better options available. [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: @MoneerKamal I have two spans, one inside the other. I was hoping that the inside span would inherit all styling from the outer one

Comment: @Serlite thanks for pointing this out. This is indeed what is happening. I did not know about this issue. In fact, if I apply other styles (like font color, for example) they do get assigned to both elements.

Comment: @Paulie_D You are absolutely right. I got this same answer several times when posting to Stackoverflow about positioning. I am working with ePub-format ebooks (pages are HTML5) in a way that I need to absolutely position words/sentences in the page. I will though check the website to see if any other workaround is possible in my case.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show border-bottom in your absolute span then add again in your absolute div

```
<span style="border-bottom: 2px solid red;">
    <span style="position:absolute; left:50px; top:50px;border-bottom: 2px solid red;">Hello</span> how are you
</span>
```

[here is fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smkexpza/1/)

Comment: Thanks @sanjay-gohil. This achieves the end goal, but does not solve my problem of applying a single style to a group of elements.

Comment: single style to group not working on position:absolute span because not consider your parent span. its like separate span